# Append to dynamic element?

Tags: jquery

I have records from a database which contains parent-child data for each record. I'm attempting to create a parent-child list, but I'm having problems creating the child lists:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var objCategories = new Object ({
        id: 0
    });
    $('#load-structures').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        objCategories.id = $(this).attr("data-category");
        categories();
    });
    function categories() {
        $(".flash").show();
        $(".flash").fadeIn(400).html("Loading...");
            $.ajax({
                url: base_url + "notes/jq_get_structures/" + objCategories.id,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                success: function (element) {
                    $(".flash").hide();
                    $(".load-link").addClass("link-none");
                    for (var i=0;i<element.length;i++) {
                        if (element[i].parent == 0) {
                            $("#links-structures-parents").append('<li id="structure-parent-' + element[i].structure_id + '"><a href="#structures" title="View ' + element[i].name + '" class="structures">&lsquo;' + element[i].name + '&rsquo;</a></li>');
                        } else if (element[i].parent > 0) {
                            if ($('#structure-children-' + element[i].structure_id).length) {
                                $("#structure-children-" + element[i].structure_id).append('<li id="structure-child-' + element[i].structure_id + '"><a href="#structures" title="View ' + element[i].name + '" class="structures">&lsquo;' + element[i].name + '&rsquo;</a></li>');
                            } else {
                                $("#structure-parent-" + element[i].structure_id).html('<ul id="structure-children-' + element[i].structure_id + '">');
                                $("#structure-parent-" + element[i].structure_id).html('<li id="structure-child-' + element[i].structure_id + '"><a href="#structures" title="View ' + element[i].name + '" class="structures">&lsquo;' + element[i].name + '&rsquo;</a></li>');
                                $("#structure-parent-" + element[i].structure_id).html('</ul>');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    $("#links-structures-parents").empty();
                    $("#links-structures-parents").append('<li>There are no Structures.</li>');
                }
            }
        );
    }
});
```

There are no problems with the data itself, but is instead the conditional part whereby I attempt to create the child lists.

I have some [example code](http://jsfiddle.net/WayneSmallman/Vr6EU/8/), though for the life of me, I can't get it to run with the data locally, but I'm hoping someone knows what the trick is.

Comment: you do not exactly say what the problem is, just that you have one.

Comment: @Anton, it's there, so I'm not sure how you're not seeing it.

Comment: @PatrickEvans "... but is instead the conditional part whereby I attempt to create the child lists." I can't create child lists.

Comment: @WayneSmallman, you have to tell jsfiddle to include jquery, its the select box at the left top, currently you have nothing selected

Comment: @WayneSmallman, that tells us nothing of the problem, what about the conditional part is not working?

Comment: @PatrickEvans, thanks for that. I'm very much in the learning phases with jQuery, and JSFiddle, evidently.

Comment: Version with jQuery included & using jsFiddle's echo API: http://jsfiddle.net/Vr6EU/5/

Comment: @PatrickEvans the code inside the conditional statement isn't creating the child lists.

Comment: Guys, I've updated the code; there was a unescaped single quote in there.

Answer (score 0):

your code in the else statement rewrites the html code, so the last call just makes the element have `</ul>`, you need to either add the previous html code with the new part or do it all in one swoop.

```
else {
    var eleobj = $("#structure-parent-" + element[i].structure_id);
    eleobj.html('<ul id="structure-children-' + element[i].structure_id + '">');
    eleobj.html(eleobj.html()+'<li id="structure-child-' + element[i].structure_id + '"><a href="#structures" title="View ' + element[i].name + '" class="structures">&lsquo;' + element[i].name + '&rsquo;</a></li>');
    eleobj.html(eleobj.html()+'</ul>');

    //Though you could do this in one call
    eleobj.html(
        '<ul id="structure-children-' + element[i].structure_id + '">'+
        '<li id="structure-child-' + element[i].structure_id + '">'+
        '<a href="#structures" title="View ' + element[i].name + '" class="structures">&lsquo;' + element[i].name + '&rsquo;</a>' +
        '</li></ul>'
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but they're riddled with errors (assuming they're separate), and since I don't understand what you're doing, I don't know how to fix them.

Comment: I've taken the whole of the updated code sample and replaced the last else statement with it, but it's doing anything.

Comment: only error i see was i didnt have the last `+` on the last of the concatenations. the only thing i added in the first part was add the eleobj.html()+ part which is adding the previous contents of the element to the string. In the second part i just concatenate the whole thing together so to only do one call.

Comment: Yeah, I made that first comment based on your original code, with the second comment afterwards. As I said, it doesn't do anything, though there are no errors, either.

Comment: is the else ever reached, and is there an element that has that specific id in the DOM? you can check by doing a `console.log(eleobj.length);` which should show a number in the javascript console, if it is 0 then it hasnt found any element with that id.

Comment: Yes, it's always triggered the else statement. However, eleobj.length is 0.

Comment: I think this is something to do with appending, or adding to, a dynamic element. I've seen this kind of thing before, which required using live(), but that only appears to operate in the context of an event.

Comment: I've just tried out that theory and it is the dynamic aspect that is preventing it from working, perhaps a binding issue?

Comment: if eleobj is 0 it means your element hasnt been added to the DOM yet

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I need to know how I add those elements to the DOM.

Comment: the same way you do in the `if` part of the `if else` statement, use the `.append` function on whatever element you need to add the element to.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, in the end, it was an issue with the parent-child id attributes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var objCategories = new Object ({
        id: 0
    });
    $('#load-structures').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        objCategories.id = $(this).attr("data-category");
        categories();
    });
    function categories() {
        $(".flash").show();
        $(".flash").fadeIn(400).html("Loading...");
            $.ajax({
                url: base_url + "notes/jq_get_structures/" + objCategories.id,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                success: function (element) {
                    $(".flash").hide();
                    $(".load-link").addClass("link-none");
                    for (var i=0;i<element.length;i++) {
                        if (element[i].parent == 0) {
                            $("#links-structures-parents").append('<li id="structure-parent-' + element[i].structure_id + '"><a href="#structures" title="View ' + element[i].name + '" class="structures">&lsquo;' + element[i].name + '&rsquo;</a>');
                        } else if (element[i].parent > 0) {
                            var htmlElementParent = $("#structure-parent-" + element[i].parent);
                            var htmlElementChild = $("#structure-children-" + element[i].parent);
                            var htmlElementChildren = $("ul#structure-children-" + element[i].parent + " li");
                            if (htmlElementChildren.length == 0) {
                                htmlElementParent.append(
                                    '<ul id="structure-children-' + element[i].parent + '">' +
                                    '<li id="structure-child-' + element[i].structure_id + '">' +
                                    '<a href="#structures" title="View ' + element[i].name + '" class="structures">&lsquo;' + element[i].name + '&rsquo;</a>' +
                                    '</li></ul>'
                                );
                            } else if (htmlElementChildren.length > 0) {
                                htmlElementChild.append(
                                    '<li id="structure-child-' + element[i].structure_id + '">' +
                                    '<a href="#structures" title="View ' + element[i].name + '" class="structures">&lsquo;' + element[i].name + '&rsquo;</a>' +
                                    '</li>'
                                );
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    $("#load-structures").hide();
                },
                error: function () {
                    $("#links-structures-parents").empty();
                    $("#links-structures-parents").append('<li>There are no Structures.</li>');
                }
            }
        );
    }
});
```

Here, you'll see that I'm appending to unnumbered lists whose id attributes contain the parent values, which then feeds the list items into their respective and proper unnumbered lists.